# How to specify two or more gateways in dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq

I am using Dnsmasq on ubuntu12.04 for DHCP server.And in my LAN that has two routers,then I want to specify two gateways address for different devices.So does it support this function? And if it support, how to specify?

Answer (score 10):

all.After trying it, I fix it by anther thread.The thread is here:

- To set tag in dhcp-range

  ```
  dhcp-range=set:tag0,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.150,infinite
  dhcp-range=set:tag1,192.168.1.151,192.168.1.245,infinite
  ```
- To specify mac address and host ip

  ```
  dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,hosta,192.168.1.11,infinite
  dhcp-host=66:55:44:33:22:11,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,hostb,192.168.1.12,infinite
  ```
- To set tag in options file.

  ```
  dhcp-option=tag:tag0,option:router,192.168.1.1
  dhcp-option=tag:tag1,option:router,192.168.1.2
  ```

Then, I find that it's works. I hope these can help others!

Answer (score 5):

all.I fixed it(wrt specify two or more routers in the same subnet) and I will post what I have got here in case it can help someone else.
My requirement was handing out different routers to different hosts in the same subnet.

```
dhcp-range=set:tag0,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.200,infinite

# tag0 network
dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,hosta,192.168.1.11,infinite,set:tag0
dhcp-host=66:55:44:33:22:11,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,hostb,192.168.1.12,infinite,set:tag1
```

Then, to specify different routers to different hosts.

```
# options
dhcp-option=tag:tag0,option:router,192.168.1.1
dhcp-option=tag:tag1,option:router,192.168.1.2
```

some other notes / context that i found helpful about this, and also about the net / set / tag options:

- The optional set: sets an alphanumeric label which marks this network so that dhcp options may be specified on a per-network basis. When it is prefixed with 'tag:' instead, then its meaning changes from setting a tag to matching it. Only one tag may be set, but more than one tag may be matched.
- More than one tag can be set in a dhcp-host directive (but not in other places where "set:" is allowed)
- This system evolved from an earlier, more limited one and for backward compatibility "net:" may be used instead of "tag:" and "set:" may be omitted. (Except in dhcp-host, where "net:" may be used instead of "set:".) For the same reason, '#' may be used instead of '!' to indicate NOT.

therefore i think it's safe to just:

- use set and tag, and avoid using net (since it's the old way)
- use set in your dhcp-range and dhcp-host, to assign the tags, and
- use tag in your options to match the tags that you've already set.
- as an aside on of those dhcp-hosts you can see with multiple mac addresses, because it's the eth0 and wlan mac's for the same box.

seems to work for me anyway, perhaps this will help someone.